# How to pass session over fancyupload

Tags: php, session, fancyupload

This question might have been there, but it's answered really generally, I'd appreciate if somebody tell me exactly how to pass the session variables and retrieve them.

I already set appendCookieData: true in swiffuploader options. How do I pass the session variables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

fancyupload will set `$_POST['PHPSESSID']` based on the session cookie.

Assuming that you have php on the server side
make sure that the script that receives the the files starts the session like:

```
if(isset($_POST['PHPSESSID'])) {
    session_id($_POST['PHPSESSID']); 
}
session_start();
```